# Magento 2 "New Products" Widget Bug?

Tags: magento2

I added a Widget for all new Products to show on the Front Page, but the **"Positioning"** is kinda strange..

As you see in the image below..

[image]

Shouldn't it work out of the box? (It's a pre-made widget from Magento 2.)

Answer (score 1):

You just have make changes in css file.

If you are calling this Widget in Homepage only then in your local `cms_index_index.xml` add following code to add custom css file for homepage only.

```
<head>
    <css src="css/index.min.css" />
</head>
```

Then make changes in CSS to render products properly for that widget.

P.S. Use parent class so that it won't disturb others.